# PHP only showing 500 error

Tags: php

Hello everyone I am new to PHP and discussing my problem with a simple example

I have a code on my file **index.php**

```
<?php
   echo $a;
?>
```

When I run this code on my local server it show me the error-

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a in D:\My website\index.php on line 5
```

But when I host this file on server and run then it show following error-

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Why its not showing actual error as it show on my local server ?

Comment: Different error reporting settings.

Comment: I believe your local server is showing the error message and your web server is showing a generic 500 page. If you want to display the error message on your web server, which I'd advise against, see this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx (presuming you're running IIS).

Comment: @BeingSunny I have putted error_reporting(E_ALL); before echo $a but still getting same error message

Comment: To see the actual error load the page on the server or check the error log. To fix the error you've mentioned here define $a.

Comment: It may very well have something to do with a setting in your `.ini` file(s). Something may be commented out.

Comment: This might be relevant, http://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7. Also might be a better question for serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the web server, not from PHP.

It seems (google search) that the message "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed" is coming from IIS, the web server of Microsoft.

IIS must be configured to be able to execute PHP files.

You can read about this configuration [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh994589.aspx)